# How do I reject writing value to Firebase if have the same value in my DB? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating my custom order id with auto-increment generator function for my project. I will state my question here, if you want to know the whole story please read below.

As written in the title, I need a way to reject my [set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) to Firebase and it has to be done in 1 query. Currently, it will write my orderID to Firebase without rejecting it. But I need to reject if there is the same ID in the table.

The short version of my code will be posted here, the whole function will be posted below.

```
  firebase.database().ref('orderCounter/orderIDsChecker/'+orderID).set({
    id: orderID,
  }, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Order ID fail to generate. Regenerating new ID')
      createOrderID(orderCounterRef);
    } else {
      console.log('Order ID created!')  
    }
  });
}
```

The story,

I'm creating my own custom order id with auto-increment generator function for my project. The problem is that if multiple users creating order at the same time, it will generate the same id. Yes, I can use [transaction()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) to solve the problem but I have no idea how to use it. Therefore, I have created my own version of the "transaction". With my method, I am able to prevent duplicates id unless 2 or more users create order within 1 second of gap. Or if anyone is kind enough to show me an example of how to write a transaction for my function, I thank you in advance.

The flow of the code is,

Get "currentMonth" and "orderIdCounter" from Firebase -> orderIdCounter +1 and update to Firebase -> start the process of generating order id -> Send the generated id to firebase -> If return success "order ID created", If not "got duplicate id" Re-run the whole process.

Below is the code for my order id generator function.

```
function createOrderID(orderCounterRef){
  var childData = [];
  var orderID;

  //Get the Current Month and Order ID Counter from Firebase
  orderCounterRef.on('value', function(snap) { childData = snapshotToArrayWithoutID(snap); });

  var currentMonth = childData[0];
  var orderIDCounter = childData[1];

  if (orderIDCounter !== undefined){
    //Update orderIDCounter on Firebase. 
    //This is to prevent duplicate orderID when multiple users is creating order at the same time.
    var IDCounter = parseInt(orderIDCounter) + 1;
    //Set IDCounter to 3 digits
    IDCounter = ('00' + IDCounter.toString()).slice(-3);
    firebase.database().ref('orderCounter/orderIDCounter').set(IDCounter);

    //Handle the process to generate Order ID. Return in YYMMxxx(auto increment) format.
    orderID = handleCreateOrderID(currentMonth, (parseInt(orderIDCounter) - 1));

    //Check if duplicate ID on firebase
    firebase.database().ref('orderCounter/orderIDsChecker/'+orderID).set({
      id: orderID,
    }, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Order ID fail to generate. Regenerating new ID')
        createOrderID(orderCounterRef);
      } else {
        console.log('Order ID created!')  
      }
    });
  }
  return orderID;
}
```

My DB:

[image: DB Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @samthecodingman & @Renaud Tarnec for your advice.

I took @samthecodingman's code and change a bit to fit my project. But I use `generateOrderID()` only to call the result and it works well. But you won't get any value with just the code. I call out another function (`connectToFirebase`) whenever users enter the page. I am not sure why it works or if this is the right way, but it works for me and that's good enough.

```
export  function generateOrderID(){
  var orderId;
  var childData = [];

  const orderCounterRef = firebase.database().ref('orderCounter/');

  //Get the Current Month from Firebase
  orderCounterRef.on('value', function(snap) { childData = snapshotToArrayWithoutID(snap); });

  //Check ID format YYMMXXX (XXX=auto_increment). Hanlde auto_increment for Year and Month 
  handleOrderIdFormat(childData[0], orderCounterRef)

  //transaction
  orderCounterRef.child('orderId').transaction(function(currentId) {
    orderId = (currentId||0) +1;
    return orderId;
  }, function(err) {
    if( err ) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  });
  return orderId;
}
```

```
export  function connectToFirebase(){ 
  //Connection Firebase Database
  const orderCounterRef = firebase.database().ref('orderCounter/');
  orderCounterRef.on('value', function(snap) {  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed use a [`transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction) as you have mentioned in your question.

The following should do the trick:

```
  //Declare a function that increment a counter in a transaction
  function createOrderID() {
    var orderIdRef = firebase.database().ref('orderId');
    return orderIdRef.transaction(function(currentId) {
      return currentId + 1;
    });
  }


  //Call the asynchronous createOrderID() function
  createOrderID().then(function(transactionResult) {
    console.log(transactionResult.snapshot.val());
  });
```

---

If you want to start the counter at a specific value, just create an `orderId` node in your database and assign a specific value to it, e.g; `1912000`.

If you just want to start at 1, you don't need to create a node, it will be automatically created with the first call to the `createOrderID()` function.

Comment: Side note: Personally I would call the value returned from the transaction's promise `result` or `transactionResult` to make it clearer that it is an object with keys `committed` and `snapshot` rather than the value of `id`.

Comment: Good suggestion @samthecodingman! :-) I've adapted the answer.

Comment: Hi, Happy New Year! Thank you for your reply, I have tested with your transaction. But now the problem is that my id returns as null because of the time required to retrieve data with the transaction. I get the id after it runs the rest of the code. What should I do about it? Thank you again!

Comment: I will try to use transaction for this matter. But back to the original question of this post, how do I reject writing a value to Firebase if I have the same value in my DB?

Comment: @Kenneth128 Happy New year to you too! "I get the id after it runs the rest of the code" -> As explained in the answer, the `createOrderID()` function is asynchronous, therefore you have to use its result within the `then()` function, as shown at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: "How do I reject writing a value to Firebase if I have the same value in my DB" -> The only way is to read the database before writing to it. And this shall **again** be done within a transaction. You would read the value at `'orderCounter/orderIDsChecker/' + orderID` and if it does not exist you write a new value. However, treating the case it exists is more tricky because you have indeed to increment `orderID` and try again. This is, among other reasons, why having a counter is usually the approach used for your use case.